# Data from get to Global Variable

Tags: ionic-framework, get, ionic3

first of all iwant to apologize for my poor englis, im trying to resolve this by my own for few days and i couldn't, i really need to solve this for a school project.
I have a variable named "myAccountData", im trying to put GET HTTP request result on it but its not working here's my code:
**Page.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import { EditaccountPage } from '../editaccount/editaccount';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../../providers/auth-service/auth-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
/**
 * Generated class for the MyaccountPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-myaccount',
  templateUrl: 'myaccount.html',
})
export class MyaccountPage {


  public myAccountData;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private nativeStorage: NativeStorage,  public authServiceProvider: AuthServiceProvider) {

  }

  setmyAccountData(data){
    this.myAccountData=this.authServiceProvider.getData("userbyid/40").subscribe( myData => {
      this.myAccountData=myData;
    });
  }
  gotoEdit(){
    this.navCtrl.push(EditaccountPage);

  }

}
```

**authServiceProvider.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
let apiUrl = "http://192.168.1.2/api/v1/"
/*
  Generated class for the AuthServiceProvider provider. 

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider { 

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  public async postData(credentials, type): Promise<any> {

    await this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials)).toPromise();
}
  public getData(type): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get(apiUrl + type);


  }

}
```

When i run "http://192.168.1.2/api/v1/userbyid/40" on postman this is what i get: `{"id":"40","firstname":"Kebbab","lastname":"Walid","email":"walid@kebbab.fr","username":"walid","password":"a665a45920422f9d417e4867efdc4fb8a04a1f3fff1fa07e998e86f7f7a27ae3","sexe":"","birth":"2018-04-11","telephone":"0","type":"ouvrier","emailverified":"0"}`
But on page.html if i use `{{myAccountData.firstname}}` it doesnt show anything
**Error Log:**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _co.myAccountData is undefined
View_MyaccountPage_0/<@ng:///AppModule/MyaccountPage.ngfactory.js:128:13
updateRenderer@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14342:20
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13866:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14211:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14143:13
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13867:5
ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11653:9
NavControllerBase.prototype._viewAttachToDOM@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51117:9
Tab.prototype._viewAttachToDOM@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:77128:9
NavControllerBase.prototype._transition@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:51197:13
NavControllerBase.prototype._nextTrns/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:50918:40
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14974
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4982:24
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14901
F</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10124
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20240
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887
F</h</e.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16823
p@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27646
v@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893

Stack trace:
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752
c@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19461
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20233
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15649
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4973:24
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15562
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10815
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7887
F</h</e.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16823
p@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27646
v@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893
 core.js:1350
```

Comment: Are you able to print the response in console.

Comment: @Karrthik no the variable is empty on console too

Comment: Did you check for the response in the network tab while debugging. What is the status of the call. Is it giving you 200. if the status is 200 what is the response of the call.

Comment: @Karrthik Thanks for your attention i was trying it on device, i was getting i blank page, now im trying on computer, i got the error log, i updated the post with it

Comment: Can you post your code of your html and controller to see whats really happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my page.html i usef { { myAccountData?.firstname } } instead of { { myAccountData.firstname } } and it worked